# No route found for "GET /api/doc.json" after nelmio upgrade

Tags: php, symfony, nelmioapidocbundle

I just updated `nelmio/api-doc-bundle` from 3.2 to 4.3 using composer. Now when I view `/api/doc.json` on my application (which previously showed a list of API endpoints), I get this error:

> No route found for "GET /api/doc.json"

Here is the content of `config/routes/nelmio_api_doc.yaml`:

```
app.swagger:
    path: /api/doc.json
    methods: GET
    defaults: { _controller: nelmio_api_doc.controller.swagger }
```

What do I need to change in my app in order to make my documentation endpoint work again?

Comment: Does `php bin/console debug:route` show the doc?

Comment: Yes. Here is what it shows: app.swagger GET ANY ANY /api/doc.json

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that in `nelmio_api_doc.yaml`, I just had to change this line:

`defaults: { _controller: nelmio_api_doc.controller.swagger }`

... to this:

`defaults: { _controller: nelmio_api_doc.controller.swagger_json }`

Then the route worked again.